# rspec raise_error not working with allow_any_instance

Tags: ruby, rspec3

I am trying to raise an error using the below rpsec code

```
allow_any_instance_of(ClientClass).to receive(:instance_method).and_raise(ErrorClass, 'Error raised')
```

My code which I am trying to test has an instance method

```
def to_be_tested_code
   # do some stuff
   client = ClientClass.new
   client.instance_method
   # do other stuff 
end
```

My questions:

1. The error is not getting raised when I am trying to run the test case. What am I doing wrong ?
2. I know double is recommended to mock stuff but then I have to `double` a `ClientClass` object and inject it in causing my method signature to change like this `#to_be_test_code(client_class_instance)`. Since `#to_be_test_code` is a public method I don't want to change the method signature for the sake of easy testing.